# How would I make a Custom Switch and Toggle Like this In react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am Trying to make a custom switch in react native expo but all the NPM's components don't seem to work, how would i come about creating a custom switch with animations and a custom toggle like the ones show in the image with react native expo?

[What I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS40k.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your first switch example you can look at react-native-switch and tweak it slightly to take a height and width (instead of circle size). I have a working example of this [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@tnr_c/customswitch).

For your second example a simple TouchableOpacity with toggle icon should suffice. You can get a little more elborate and add a color animation if you wanted.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the Help! 

I didn't know things like innerCircleStyle={{
          borderWidth: 0,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}

Existed with the default React native switch, and was looking all around for a component that lets me edit the inside! But I guess you learn Something Everyday! Thanks for the help